# Simple Monte Carlo on GPU using Parallel toolbox

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Here is a toy example that i put together exploring the parfoor function using the CPU to speed up executions. Even after reviewing the Parallel documentation however i am confused how to upgrade this to run on my GPU (Nvidia 980ti).

Would appreciate any pointers on how to update this code to run on GPU.

Cheers.

```
% toy example--monte carlo estimation of pi using for loops
tic;
N = 1000000000;
hitcounter = 0;
for i = 1:N
    x = rand;
    y = rand;
    if ( y < sqrt(1-x*x) )
        hitcounter = hitcounter + 1;
    end
end
disp(hitcounter/N*4)
toc;

% toy example--monte carlo estimation of pi using parfor loops
tic;
N = 1000000000;
hitcounter = 0;
parfor i = 1:N
    x = rand;
    y = rand;
    if ( y < sqrt(1-x*x) )
        hitcounter = hitcounter + 1;
    end
end
disp(hitcounter/N*4)
toc;
```

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need to do is to vectorise your code - this is always a good idea, and especially so on the GPU. Then, you simply need to build `x` and `y` directly on the GPU using the trailing argument to `rand`.

```
N = 1000000;
x = rand(1, N, 'gpuArray');
y = rand(1, N, 'gpuArray');
pi_est = sum(y < sqrt(1 - x.*x)) / N * 4;
```

Note I scaled back `N` to enable this to fit on the GPU. If you want to run with a higher value of `N` - I would suggest adding an outer loop, and essentially performing the computation in "chunks" that fit on the limited memory of the GPU.